# Allow Android to receive key events while screen is OFF

Tags: android

We are working an application on Android 4.0.4 set-top-box, we wanted to press some key to turn off the screen (connected through HDMI) and keep the box running. We are doing like:

```
/* Acquire Wake Lock */
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock lock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Tag");
lock.acquire();

/* Turn OFF screen */
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);

//lock.release(); /* box will go to sleep if lock released */
```

When we press the key, screen did go OFF, and box seems to be still running. However when we tried to press the key again in this state, it goes like:

```
I/InputDispatcher(  173): Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.
```

Is there anything we can do to detect key input in this state? or is there any other ways we can keep the box working and just turn OFF the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use WakeLock with [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) - where screen is allowed to turn off, you just have to try if the events are disabled.

By the way, the key you want to press to wake the device is hardware key or a software key on the display?

Comment: Thanks but I think we are already using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, am I using it correctly? BTW, it's a hardware key on the remote controller.